Is there any reason for grpcio not have Digicert G5 in its truststore?
I am currently using grpcio. My server exposes Digicert G5, but it failed with some certificate error. Then I noticed that the Digicert G5 is not in the grpcio truststore, under /lib/python3.11/site-packages/grpc/_cython/_credentials/roots.pem. Is there a reason for this?
I added the Digicert G5 certificate under the path. But everyone that will use it has to add the cert as well, and it is not good.
